# Vamos criar um código de uso para a tag "codificação"?

Tags: debate, status-pronto, tags, tag-específica

A *tag* [codificação](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/codifica%c3%a7%c3%a3o) é muito genérica, e por causa disto tem sido usada para várias coisas, o que é algo claramente ruim. Ela foi criada para lidar com codificação de dados, e acabou sendo usado para qualquer coisa que envolva código no assunto. Precisamos renomeá-la para outra coisa mais específica. Para o que?

Comment: O que é codificação de dados? É encriptação?

Comment: È pegar os dados e aplicar algum código nela. só isso. Encriptação é uma forma, mas não é a única forma de codificar dados. O primeiro uso da *tag* foi com Base64.

Comment: Então, codificação de dados já é amplo. Não vai ser fácil encontrar um termo.

Comment: Por que não `codificação-de-dados`?

Comment: Eu acho específico :) Porque é sobre uma coisa que faz sentido ter uma classificação. Se for aplicar esse critério para definir o que é amplo, [tag:php] é amplo porque tem um monte de assunto que pode ser tratado em PHP. Mas ela não é porque não trata de coisas diferentes. O problema da [tag:codificação] é que ela trata de coisas completamente distintas. É o mesmo problema da [tag:tabela]. Ser guarda-chuva não vejo problema, ser ambígua é problema. Perguntando o que é [tag:codificação], não sabemos sobre o que é, já [codificação-de-dados] é sobre os vários tipos de codificação de dados, nada +

Comment: É uma boa e óbvia sugestão, mas queria ter opiniões.

Comment: *"Eu acho específico"*, concordo.Quando eu disse ampla era no sentido de encontrar uma só palavra..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Só havia 12 perguntas nesta tag:

1. [Como inserir caractere de emoji num campo TEXT do MYSQL?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/324386/132)
2. [problem with R enconding](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/261524/132)
3. [Retorno de "?" ao invés dos caracteres especiais em um SELECT](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/217045/132)
4. [Como corrigir esses caracteres errados �PNG IHDR2f�iePLTE������IDAT�c��][�IEND�B�?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/214357/132)
5. [Atom não salva na codificação correta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/205659/132)

   Nestas 5 perguntas, eu removi a tag [codificação](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/codifica%c3%a7%c3%a3o) e coloquei a tag [character-encoding](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/character-encoding) em seu lugar.

---

6. [Como transformar código fonte em resumo digital hash?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/294344/132)
7. [O que é um código depreciado?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/178138/132)
8. [Rótulo não aparece no gráfico](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/168498/132)

   Nestas 3 perguntas, eu removi a tag [codificação](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/codifica%c3%a7%c3%a3o) que não tinha nada a ver com essas perguntas.

---

9. [Codificar uma URL é importante?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/271204/132)

   Removi a tag [codificação](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/codifica%c3%a7%c3%a3o) que não era necessária na pergunta. Nesse caso, talvez uma tag [url-encoding](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/url-encoding) poderia ser usada.

---

10. [Codificaçao de bits](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/270059/132)

    Pergunta fora do escopo, mal-formulada, não clara o suficiente e ampla demais. Removi a tag [codificação](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/codifica%c3%a7%c3%a3o) e votei para fechar.

---

11. [Ajuda com código(parece ser hexadecimal)](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/160578/132)

    Removi a tag [codificação](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/codifica%c3%a7%c3%a3o) e coloquei a tag [criptografia](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/criptografia) em seu lugar.

---

12. [Como codificar e decodificar strings base64 em C?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/150371/132)

    Removi a tag [codificação](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/codifica%c3%a7%c3%a3o) pois não era necessária.

---

Assim sendo, a tag [codificação](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/codifica%c3%a7%c3%a3o) foi esvaziada e deletada. Não fará falta.

Comment: A última não é criptografia, nem de perto, a penúltima também parece não ser.

Comment: @Maniero. Ok, a 12 não é criptografia, embora a tag estivesse lá (acabei de removê-la também). Nessa daí, a tag base-64 é suficiente. Quanto a penúltima, é criptografia sim, apenas é uma criptografia bem simples e fácil de quebrar (e o propósito do exercício era exatamente a de quebrá-la).